# What does this iptables rule's options mean?

Tags: iptables

The rule is

```
-A KUBE-SEP-G3HEJMIUHDVUA2GR -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination
```

which is part of a kube service rule:

```
-N KUBE-SEP-G3HEJMIUHDVUA2GR
-A KUBE-SEP-G3HEJMIUHDVUA2GR -s 10.233.64.2/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-G3HEJMIUHDVUA2GR -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination
```

As I know normally this rule would have a specific destination like this one:

```
-A KUBE-SEP-XEZU3EBQ2WW4MLUB -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx:https" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.233.116.87:443
```

while the first one don't have a specific desitination which might because this service has only one endpoint, but I want to know:

1. What does the destination ":0" mean?
2. Why "--destination" appears three times?
3. What is the use of "--persistent" here?
4. Where can I find more detailed document about DNAT target?

Comment: check this out https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html

Comment: @Consideratus I have read DNAT target on this site, but didn't find explaination for ":0" , the multiple "--destination" and "--persistent"

Comment: Apologize for that I really thought I've read the description there. 

Anyway, according to manual 

"For those kernels, if you specify more than one destination address, either via an address range or multiple --to-destination options, a simple round-robin (one after another in cycle) load balancing takes place between these addresses"

The --persistent option is unknown to me and I cannot find it anywhere. 

The :0 port I believe means dynamic port allocation. Here is some information https://www.lifewire.com/port-0-in-tcp-and-udp-818145

Comment: No need to apologize. I found explaination for "--persistent" at netfilter's documents: https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html, checkout the DNAT part.

Comment: Nice, so you've found the answers :). Now I see why I wasn't able to find info in manual for the iptables. I didn't know about existence of extensions. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 0):

This exactly is not an anwser. After digging more, I found the iptables rules in kube-proxy container are different from iptables rule on host machine.

```
 -N KUBE-SEP-OYL6BTTAC4W4HXLZ
-A KUBE-SEP-OYL6BTTAC4W4HXLZ -s 10.233.64.38/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-OYL6BTTAC4W4HXLZ -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination
```

(the name and ip changed because I reboot my machine)

Then I checked the versions of both iptables cli and found they are not mached. I upgraded the kernel before, this might cause some problems. But I don't want to dig more, I'm not an expert of kernel.